# jQuery - Change id according to the value selected from the select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the id of the `select` field with a JS function, please take a look at my HTML and JS code.

HTML:

`<select name="cat-parent" id="change_id();">
                <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="category-2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="category-3">Category 3</option>
        <option value="category-4">Category 4</option>
        <option value="category-2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="category-1">Category 1</option>
    </select>`

JS:

`function change_id(){
        var idSuffix = jQuery(this).val();
        return 'example' + idSuffix; 
 }`

Comment: I think you need to make use of `onchange="change_id();"`

Comment: You will need to use `$(document).ready()` to attach a new ID when the document DOM has loaded and then get the selected option using `$(this).find("option:selected").val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `change` event handler.

```
$('[name=cat-parent]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).attr("id", 'example' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! Do I have to wrap this inside `function change_id(){}` ?

Comment: you don't need that. Just delete it and the id attribute

Comment: I think a shorter and probably faster way would be: `this.id = 'example' + this.value;`.